# If the floating-point number storage on a certain system has a sign bit, a 3-bit exponent, and a 4-bit significand:

Tags: floating-point, signed

(Assume no bits are implied, there is no biasing, exponents use two’s complement notation, and exponents of all zeros and all ones are allowed.)
I am trying to find the largest and smallest number that can be represented if the system is normalized. I thought that the largest number would be:

```
.1111 x 2^4 = 0 100 1111 = 15
```

and the smallest:

```
1.0 x 2^-4 = 0 000 0001 = 0.0625
```

But the answers that I saw were:

```
Largest: .1111 x 2^3 = 111.1 = 7.5

Smallest: 0.1 x 2^-4 = .00001 = 0.03125
```

I do not understand how either answer would even be possible in a 4-bit significand.

Comment: There are multiple floating-point formats, even given the number of bits for each field. What is the bias for the exponent field? Is the maximum exponent field value reserved for infinities and NaNs? Is the minimum value reserved for subnormals? Is there an “implicit” leading bit for the significand. No good textbook or teacher gives a problem like this without some discussion of these. You need to add this information to your question.

Comment: This is some of the question that I missed including. I have done some floating-point problems, but not finding the max and min. The teacher that I have does not have a book for the class. Assume no bits are implied, there is no biasing, exponents use two’s complement notation, and exponents of all zeros and all ones are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

There're a few things to decipher here.

- Exponent: 3-bits, 2's complement, no bias. This means the exponent can represent values in the range `-4` (corresponding to `100`) to `3` (corresponding to `011`).
- Normalized without implied bit: This means significand always starts with a `1`.

When you put these together, the maximum number you can write is:

```
 0 011 1111 = 2^3 * (2^-1 + 2^-2 + 2^-3 + 2^-4) = 7.5
```

Since floating point values are symmetic around `0`, the minumum value you can write is `-7.5` by flipping the sign bit above. But I guess your teacher is going for minumum strictly positive (i.e., non-zero) value. In that case, we pick the exponent to be as small as possible, and just keep the first bit of the significand to satisfy the normalized requirement. We get:

```
 0 100 1000 = 2^-4 * 2^-1 = 2^-5 = 0.03125
```

Hope that makes sense!